# How to generate a new column which the values are between two existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to add a new column based on the values of two existing columns.

My data set looks like this:

```
                         Date      Bid      Ask  Last  Volume
0      2021.02.01 00:01:02.327  1.21291  1.21336   0.0       0
1      2021.02.01 00:01:21.445  1.21290  1.21336   0.0       0
2      2021.02.01 00:01:31.912  1.21287  1.21336   0.0       0
3      2021.02.01 00:01:32.600  1.21290  1.21336   0.0       0
4      2021.02.01 00:02:08.920  1.21290  1.21338   0.0       0
...                        ...      ...      ...   ...     ...
80356  2021.02.01 23:58:54.332  1.20603  1.20605   0.0       0
```

and I need to generate a new column named "New" and the values of column "New" needs to have a random number between Column "Bid" and Column "Ask". For each value of the column "New", it has to be in the range from Bid to Ask (can equal to Bid or Ask).

I have tried to do like this

```
df['rand_between'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.random.randint(x.Ask,x.Bid), axis=1)
```

But I got this

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
low >= high
```

I am new to Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`np.random.uniform`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) so you get a random float with equal probability between your high and low bounds with closure [low_bound, high_bound).

Also ditch the `apply`; np.random.uniform can generate the numbers using arrays of bounds. (I added a row at the bottom to make this obvious).

```
import numpy as np
df['New'] = np.random.uniform(df.Bid, df.Ask, len(df))
```

---

```
                      Date        Bid        Ask  Last  Volume         New
0 2021.02.01  00:01:02.327    1.21291    1.21336   0.0       0    1.213114
1 2021.02.01  00:01:21.445    1.21290    1.21336   0.0       0    1.212969
2 2021.02.01  00:01:31.912    1.21287    1.21336   0.0       0    1.213342
3 2021.02.01  00:01:32.600    1.21290    1.21336   0.0       0    1.212933
4 2021.02.01  00:02:08.920    1.21290    1.21338   0.0       0    1.212948
5 2021.02.01  00:02:08.920  100.00000  115.00000   0.0       0  100.552836
```

Comment: Actually, I don't think the upper bound is included in `uniform`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Oh good point. The docs seem to contradict, but I'm guessing the part in the arguments about "All values generated will be less than or equal to high." is likely a slopy copy paste

Comment: Maybe I was reading the [old doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html). That was my impression with all `random`, but I guess they changed the default behavior in the recent versions.

Comment: It's probably not a huge point to worry about. In the docs example they explicitly check `<` for the  upper bound, but they also state that due to floating point imprecision the value _could_ include the upper bound so their example _could_ fail, but in practice it's so unlikely

Comment: OMG thank you so much! it worked. Does random. Does this function random.uniform allow to have the values equal to the band values?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is switch the order of x.Ask and x.Bid in your code.  In your dataframe, the ask prices are always higher than the bid, that's why you are getting the error:

```
df['rand_between'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.random.randint(x.Bid,x.Ask), axis=1)
```

If your ask value is sometimes greater and sometimes less than the bid, use:

```
df['rand_between'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.random.randint(x.Bid,x.Ask) if x.Ask > x.Bid else np.random.randint(x.Ask,x.Bid), axis=1)
```

Finally, if it is possible for ask to be greater, less than or equal to bis, use:

```
def helper(x):
    if x.Ask > x.Bid:
        return np.random.randint(x.Bid,x.Ask)
    elif x.Bid > x.Ask:
        return np.random.randint(x.Ask, x.Bid)
    else:
        return None
df['rand_between'] = df.apply(helper, axis=1)
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried to switch the order, but I still got the same error message.

Comment: Is it possible that in your data sometimes the ask price is greater and sometimes it is less than the bid price? If so, I have a different solution.

Comment: @Susie See my updated answer that covers all the bases, depending on what your data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the rows using `apply` and then use your `randint` function (for floats you might want to use `random.uniform`).  For example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: from random import randint
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'bid':range(10),'ask':range(0,20,2)})
   ...: 
   ...: df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: randint(x['bid'],x['ask']), axis=1)
   ...: df
Out[1]: 
   bid  ask  new
0    0    0    0
1    1    2    1
2    2    4    4
3    3    6    6
4    4    8    6
5    5   10    9
6    6   12    9
7    7   14   12
8    8   16   13
9    9   18    9
```

The `axis=1` is telling the `apply` function to loop over rows, not columns.